# Zsh PROJECT environment variable

Tags: zsh

I've been trying to find out how to set the directory for a rope project for ropevim to find automatically (I still haven't succeeded in this), and in doing this I have discovered the `$PROJECT` environment variable in `zsh`.

Once I set this variable to a specific path, for instance the root of my project

```
~ # cd my_project_folder
~/my_project_folder # export PROJECT=`pwd`
```

The prompt is changed so that all paths are printed as relative to `PROJECT`, the project root, like so

```
PROJECT # cd sub_folder
PROJECT/sub_folder #
```

which is pretty neat as it shortens the path, but I would like to change the prompt to display for instance the project name instead of `PROJECT`.

I have tried to search the `zsh` documentation for any mention of this environment variable, but no luck. Has anyone encountered this variable before? `bash` seems to ignore this environment variable.

Comment: There's nothing special about the variable name `PROJECT`, what you're seeing is just the effect of a zsh "named directory". (As pointed out in the the answer below.) You might equally well have called your variable `PROJECT1`, or `FOOBAR` or anything else for that matter, it's the fact that it contains a path name that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably make use of a project specific [named directory](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshexpn/).

For example, with a directory structure:

```
~/projects/foo
~/projects/foo/bar
```

in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
FOO=~/projects/foo
```

your prompt could look similar to this:

```
 ~/projects  #ls
foo
 ~/projects  #cd foo 
 ~FOO  #ls
 bar
 ~/FOO  #cd bar
 ~/FOO/bar  #
```

This uses [`%~`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/) to expand the current directory within the prompt:

> As  **`%d`**  and **`%/`**, but if the current working directory has a named directory as its prefix, that part is replaced by a **`~`** followed by the name of the directory.

(found under "SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES" in the linked `man zshmisc` page).

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now. I was thinking it was a special variable name. This is really cool, thank you.